# R, Python or Excel. How can I count time range occurrences happening during other time ranges?

Tags: python, r, excel, powerbi

Say for example, I want to count how many people are in a room while others are in that room for each day. When that person leaves, I want an updated count of how many are in that room. This feels like it should be the most simple question in history, yet I am completely stumped. See table to understand what I am working with.

These times are meant to be checked every 15 minutes and thus are recorded as full duration of their stay in 15 minute intervals.

I have access to R, Python, Excel and Power BI and am fairly familiar with each. So if anyone can help using any of those languages I would be entirely grateful.

Cheers!

```
ID    |  Date      |  Start Time | End Time |
11111 |  09/01/21  |  0900       | 1700     |
22222 |  09/01/21  |  1000       | 1300     | 
33333 |  09/01/21  |  0900       | 1200     |  
44444 |  09/02/21  |  0900       | 1700     | 
55555 |  09/02/21  |  1200       | 1500     |
66666 |  09/02/21  |  0945       | 1400     | 
77777 |  09/02/21  |  1000       | 1230     |
88888 |  09/02/21  |  0900       | 1445     |
99999 |  09/02/21  |  1300       | 1700     |
```

Edit: Both [Langtang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4447540/langtang) and [Maël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460602/ma%C3%ABl)'s solution worked well for me, but I ultimately ended up using something very similar to langtang's solution for my project. Here is the code langtang provided:

============================================================================

library(data.table)

```
# set to data.table, and create datetime columns sdate and edate
setDT(dt)[
,c("sdate","edate"):=lapply(.SD, \(x) 
lubridate::mdy_hm(paste(Date,x))),
.SDcols = c("Start Time", "End Time")
 ] 

 dt[, in_room:=sapply(edate, \(x) sum(sdate<x & edate>x)), by=Date] 
 [,`:=`(sdate=NULL, edate=NULL)]
```

============================================================================

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with the `ivs` and `tidyverse` libraries in R:

```r
library(ivs)
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Start.Time = mdy_hm(paste(Date, Start.Time)),
         End.Time = mdy_hm(paste(Date, End.Time)),
         ivs = iv(Start.Time, End.Time))

bounds <- range(df$ivs)
lower <- iv_start(bounds[[1]])
upper <- iv_end(bounds[[2]]) - 1L

tibble(minutes = seq(lower, upper, by = 15 * 60),
       count = iv_count_between(minutes, df$ivs)) %>% 
  group_by(gp = data.table::rleid(count)) %>% 
  summarise(StartTime = min(minutes),
            EndTime = max(minutes),
            count = unique(count))

# A tibble: 14 × 4
      gp StartTime           EndTime             count
   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
 1     1 2021-09-01 09:00:00 2021-09-01 09:45:00     2
 2     2 2021-09-01 10:00:00 2021-09-01 11:45:00     3
 3     3 2021-09-01 12:00:00 2021-09-01 12:45:00     2
 4     4 2021-09-01 13:00:00 2021-09-01 16:45:00     1
 5     5 2021-09-01 17:00:00 2021-09-02 08:45:00     0
 6     6 2021-09-02 09:00:00 2021-09-02 09:30:00     2
 7     7 2021-09-02 09:45:00 2021-09-02 09:45:00     3
 8     8 2021-09-02 10:00:00 2021-09-02 11:45:00     4
 9     9 2021-09-02 12:00:00 2021-09-02 12:15:00     5
10    10 2021-09-02 12:30:00 2021-09-02 12:45:00     4
11    11 2021-09-02 13:00:00 2021-09-02 13:45:00     5
12    12 2021-09-02 14:00:00 2021-09-02 14:30:00     4
13    13 2021-09-02 14:45:00 2021-09-02 14:45:00     3
14    14 2021-09-02 15:00:00 2021-09-02 16:45:00     2
```

data

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~ID,      ~Date, ~Start.Time, ~End.Time,
  11111L, "09/01/21",      "0900",     1700,
  22222L, "09/01/21",      "1000",     1300L,
  33333L, "09/01/21",      "0900",     1200L,
  44444L, "09/02/21",      "0900",     1700L,
  55555L, "09/02/21",      "1200",     1500L,
  66666L, "09/02/21",      "0945",     1400L,
  77777L, "09/02/21",      "1000",     1230L,
  88888L, "09/02/21",      "0900",     1445L,
  99999L, "09/02/21",      "1300",     1700L
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! However, I keep getting the same error and I'm not sure why. When running the tibble I get the error: "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number"

Comment: Does it happen also when you use the data I provide.?

Comment: I actually corrected it. This is amazing! Do you have any suggestion on how I can summarize it such that your output can be placed on the row that it is calculating from? I would like to use a Code indicating how many people were there during that time and place that code next to the individual's row. For example Code URT = 3 people, code PQ = 2 people, code AA = 1 person.Does that make sense?

Comment: Well the thing is that it changes. Would you mean the maximum number of people during the time one is in the room?*

Comment: Yes so person 11111L is there from 9 to 5 along with one other person. So the code would indicate 2 people, however at 1000 person 22222 joins and the code would indicate 3 people

Comment: look at edit. hopefully it's close to what you need

Comment: I feel so bad. Your output is what I want, but I keep getting a warning with my own dataset when trying to mutate my dataframe. Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `Start.Time = mdy_hm(paste(Date, Start.Time))`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: Problem while computing `End.Time = mdy_hm(paste(Date, End.Time))`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found.                                                                          If I proceed to summarise the tibble then I get "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number" again.

Comment: The parsing does not work. Try to look in details what's the output `paste(Date, Start.Time)`, then for `mdy_hm(paste(Date, Start.Time))`. Look at the documentation for `mdy_hm`. It's basically a problem of conversion.

Comment: I will read into it and try to understand it. Paste(Date, Start.Time) gives me a list of all the dates as a string. mdy_hm(paste(Date, Start.Time) gives me a list of NA values

Comment: You rock. I dealt with the formatting issues. It displays the correct information. However, do you have a suggestion on how I can bring that data back into the original report? I would like to see how many people are in the room during the time range of each person (each row's). That way I know what rate to bill that time range for each person. We measure in 15 minute intervals, but I would like to place the count next to each person's row on the original report.

Comment: But thé problem is that there is not a unique number of people during each person’s session. If you want the maximum you can use ivs::iv_overlaps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach, that leverages data.table.

```
library(data.table)

# set to data.table, and create datetime columns sdate and edate
setDT(dt)[
  ,c("sdate","edate"):=lapply(.SD, \(x) lubridate::mdy_hm(paste(Date,x))),
  .SDcols = c("Start Time", "End Time")
] 

dt[, in_room:=sapply(edate, \(x) sum(sdate<x & edate>x)), by=Date][,`:=`(sdate=NULL, edate=NULL)]
```

Output:

```
      ID     Date Start Time End Time in_room
   <int>   <char>     <char>   <char>   <int>
1: 11111 09/01/21      09:00    17:00       0
2: 22222 09/01/21      10:00    13:00       1
3: 33333 09/01/21      09:00    12:00       2
4: 44444 09/02/21      09:00    17:00       0
5: 55555 09/02/21      12:00    15:00       2
6: 66666 09/02/21      09:45    14:00       4
7: 77777 09/02/21      10:00    12:30       4
8: 88888 09/02/21      09:00    14:45       3
9: 99999 09/02/21      13:00    17:00       0
```

### Update

The OP has clarified that they are interested in, for each person/Date, the total number of people that were in the room with that person across the span of that person's time in the room. This is also quite simple:

```
ct_p <- function(s,e) dt[(sdate>e | edate<s)==F, .N]
dt[, overlapped:=ct_p(sdate,edate), by=1:nrow(dt)][,`:=`(sdate=NULL, edate=NULL)]
```

Output:

```
      ID     Date Start Time End Time overlapped
   <int>   <char>     <char>   <char>      <int>
1: 11111 09/01/21      09:00    17:00          3
2: 22222 09/01/21      10:00    13:00          3
3: 33333 09/01/21      09:00    12:00          3
4: 44444 09/02/21      09:00    17:00          6
5: 55555 09/02/21      12:00    15:00          6
6: 66666 09/02/21      09:45    14:00          6
7: 77777 09/02/21      10:00    12:30          5
8: 88888 09/02/21      09:00    14:45          6
9: 99999 09/02/21      13:00    17:00          5
```

Input:

```
structure(list(ID = c(11111L, 22222L, 33333L, 44444L, 55555L, 
66666L, 77777L, 88888L, 99999L), Date = c("09/01/21", "09/01/21", 
"09/01/21", "09/02/21", "09/02/21", "09/02/21", "09/02/21", "09/02/21", 
"09/02/21"), `Start Time` = c("09:00", "10:00", "09:00", "09:00", 
"12:00", "09:45", "10:00", "09:00", "13:00"), `End Time` = c("17:00", 
"13:00", "12:00", "17:00", "15:00", "14:00", "12:30", "14:45", 
"17:00")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This looks beautiful. I can replicate using your input, but I run into the issue when using my actual data: Warning messages: 1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. When I view the data I get my original dataframe along with the column that you created but filled with NA values

Comment: Notice that in my input data i fixed the start time and end time, to have a padded zero and a colon between the hours and minutes.. Also, I assume your date column is month day year, but it could be day month year (in your small example dataset, either one is valid)..  In that case, you might use the `dmy_hm()` function from lubridate

Comment: Thank you. I padded the zeroz to make start times and end times have 4 digits and included a colon between the hours and minutes. My dates are setup as yours are. The error has gone away, however I am not receiving "in_room" values as I would expect. For example My first 3 rows are on same date (10/1/21) person 1: 09:00 - 15:00, person 2: 09:00 - 15:00, person 3: 10:00 - 15:00. in_room value is 0 for all 3 of them.

Comment: If they all left at 15:00, then there is no one in the room at 15:00.. I thought I understood your original post to indicate how many people are left in the room at each time there is an "exit".

Comment: Ah,  that makes sense. I do apologize, I did not communicate very well. I was hoping to count how many people are in the room during that "session" that the person is in. If they are in there from 09:00 to 15:00 on 10/1/21 then I want to know how many other people are in there with them.

Comment: Still doesn't quite make sense.. If person 1 was in the room from 9 until 15, and say from 9 to 12 person 2 and 3 were also there, but at 12:00 person 2 left, and from 12 to 15 only person 1 and person3 were in the room. What value do you put for person 1?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you want to know how many other people were ever in the room with them during the time they were in that room (including themselves). See update

Comment: Yeah you are right. I think that I was staring at this too long and lost my sense. Thank you for posting the update!

Comment: Okay, great. So is my final solution helpful?/correct?